# This object constructor is preventing my script from running

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

I'm working on a project (creating a browser based check list).  One of my goals has been to write every piece by hand without a library like jquery or a mysql database.

Currently I'm trying to create on object for managing tasks. I'm not finished the primary function, but everything is closed, and I don't detect any errors.  Furthermore, I'm haven't iterated it or called it's functions yet, so there's nothing to reference it yet.  When I comment it out, the script runs normally.

I've included the xml request links up above and tested them successfully in a separate portion of the script.
I'm testing in firefox.
I'm writing this in SciTE

Here's the code:

```
function Task(name,node,childNode,divClass,content,onclick)
{
    function retrieveTask(node,childNode)
    {
        var taskArray = [];
        taskArray.push(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(name)[node].childNodes[childNode].nodeValue;)
        taskArray.push(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(description)[node].childNodes[childNode].nodeValue;)
        taskArray.push(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(complete)[node].childNodes[childNode].nodeValue;)
        return taskArray;
    }

    function displayTask(name,content)
    {
        var task = retrieveTask(node,childNode);
        var clickDiv = "";
        formatDiv(name,"task",task[1],clickDiv);
        task[2] === true ? formatDiv(name+1,"incompleteBox"," ",clickDiv) : formatDiv(name+1,"completeBox","O",clickDiv);
    }
}
```

If anyone could give me some insight or tips that would be awesome.  This isn't homework, it's a hobby, so it's a self teaching process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...childNodes[childNode].nodeValue;)
```

should be `);`

Comment: sorry, I didn't edit the full snippet in properly - I'm not instantiating the object, I'm defining it's constructor, so those are the parameters I've given it.  The rest of the script is not currently dependent on it, yet it prevents it from running unless commented out

Comment: If that does not fix the problem, then I think it may be something else. Could you post the complete script to jsFiddle or jsbin? The snippet you posted itself does not throw any errors, nor do I find any.

Comment: That solved the problem - I'm guessing that when the browser crawls the script it gets caught on the first one even though the function isn't being called?  (correct me if I'm wrong).  Anyway, I overlooked those completely and it's working now.  Thank you for your time, I'll try not to code when I'm exhausted in the future :s

Comment: You are right. If you are using Firefox, install the extension Firebug (if you are using chrome press F12). By doing so, you can easily find errors like this, they are displayed in the console. Even your editor should be able to find these errors (via syntax highlighting).

Comment: thanks for the tip SciTE is vary bare-bones (I don't deal well with visual clutter, I get to distracted) but Firebug is the perfect solution.  I'd uprate your solution tree if I could :)